# Wasted bytes in protocol buffer arrays?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a protocol buffer setup like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    Bar[] Bars;
}
```

A single Bar gets encoded to a 67 byte protocol buffer. This sounds about right because I know that a Bar is pretty much just a 64 byte array, and then there are 3 bytes overhead for length prefixing.

However, when I encode a Foo with an array of 20 Bars it takes 1362 bytes. 20 * 67 is 1340, so there are 22 bytes of overhead just for encoding an array!

Why does this take up so much space? And is there anything I can do to reduce it?

Comment: and the Foo itself is free? It should take some space also?

Comment: It should take some space, but 22 bytes is a lot of space!

Comment: 22 bytes on top of 1340 is not 'so much' , certainly not for a serialization. Just move on with your life.

Comment: I'm sending protocol buffers which contains 512 of these things, 4 or 5 of them every second. That's a lot of wasted bandwidth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This overhead is quite simply the information it needs to know where each of the 20 objects starts and ends. There is nothing I can do different here without breaking the format (i.e. doing something contrary to the spec).

If you really want the gory details:

An array or list is (if we exclude "packed", which doesn't apply here) simply a repeated block of sub-messages. There are two layouts available for sub-messages; strings and groups. With a string, the layout is:

```
[header][length][data]
```

where `header` is the varint-encoded mash of the wire-type and field-number (hex 08 in this case with field 1), `length` is the varint-encoded size of `data`, and data is the sub-object itself. For small objects (`data` less than 128 bytes) this often means 2 bytes overhead per object, depending on a: the field number (fields above 15 take more space), and b: the size of the data.

With a group, the layout is:

```
[header][data][footer]
```

where `header` is the varint-encoded mash of the wire-type and field-number (hex 0B in this case with field 1), `data` is the sub-object, and `footer` is another varint mash to indicate the end of the object (hex 0C in this case with field 1).

Groups are less favored generally, but they have the advantage that they don't incur any overhead as `data` grows in size. For small field-numbers (less than 16) again the overhead is 2 bytes per object. Of course, you pay double for large field-numbers, instead.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I suspected that it might be a nasty case in the protocol I was coming up against.

Answer (score 2):

By default, arrays aren't actually passed as arrays, but as repeated members, which have a little more overhead.

So I'd guess you actually have 1 byte of overhead for each repeated array element, plus 2 extra bytes overhead on top.

You can lose the overhead by using a "packed" array.  protobuf-net supports this: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

The documentation for the binary format is here: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html

Comment: Odd, using packed on the array triggers an exception "Packed buffers are not supported for wire-type: String". Which is odd, because Bar isn't a string!

Comment: @martin - as far as the protobuf spec is concerned: yes it is. This is just the name for a particular layout - it doesn't mean a *text* string. There are two possible formats for objects; strings and groups. Packed does indeed remove the overhead of headers, but only applies to very basic types such as integers and floats; not to objects.